# How to take every 3rd element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, and want to return only every third element as a new array (starting at 0).

For example:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let newArr = [1, 4, 7];
```

This is the way I am currently doing this:

```
let newArr = [];
for(let x = 0; x < arr.length; x += 3) {
   newArr.push(arr[x]);
}
return newArr;
```

Is there a way to do this with arr.map? Is there just an easier way to do this?

Comment: `.map()` would not be a good choice, because it's designed to return a 1 for 1 mapping. You could use `.reduce()` though.

Comment: @Pointy Why would I use reduce for what is in essence a filter?

Comment: @torazaburo sure, that's true. I usually think of "filter" having something to do with the intrinsic nature of the values in the list, but that's I guess just my problem :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can alternatively do it with a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),

```
let newArr = arr.filter((_,i) => i % 3 == 0);
```

But remember, using basic for loop is bit more efficient than others in some contexts.

Comment: what does `_` mean in expression `(_, i)`?

Comment: @StepUp That is just an unused argument, That's why we used an underscore there. There is no special meaning in that.

Comment: Using `filter` is not the best idea if your array is big, let's say 10,000 or so because you don't want to loop over 10,000 elements, just access them directly with a for loop as done in the question.